# Could a scalar field $g(x,y)=0$ does not define implicitly neither $x$ nor $y$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Assume for example the real valued function $g(x,y)=0$ differentiable on a open set $S$ on $\Bbb R^{2}$. If y can not be implicitly determined by $x$, and also $x$ can not be implicitly determined by $y$, what do this impies?

I was imagining that $g$ should be symmetric but I do not know whit respecct to what? For example what axe?

Comment: I believe that pondering the examples $g(x,y)=xy, g(x, y)=x^2-y^2$ can help your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}$ is a given function then
$$S:=\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\>\bigm|\>f(x,y)=0\bigr\}$$is a certain subset of the plane. If $f$ is a "reasonable" nontrivial function then we expect $S$ to be a curve, or a union of curves. But in the special case when $f(x,y):=0$ for all $(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2$ one has $S={\mathbb R}^2$, and that's all one can say.

If $f\in C^1$, and $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\ne(0,0)$ at some point $(x_0,y_0)\in S$, say $f_y(x_0,y_0)\ne0$,  then there is a rectangular window $W=[x_0-h,x_0+h]\times[y_0-h',y_0+h']$  with center $(x_0,y_0)$ and a $C^1$-function $\phi:\>[x_0-h,x_0+h]\to[y_0-h',y_0+h']$ such that
$$S\cap W=\bigl\{(x,\phi(x))\,\bigm|\,x_0-h\leq x\leq x_0+h\bigr\}\ .$$
This means that within the window $W$ the given equation $f(x,y)=0$ defines $y$ "implicitly" as a function $y=\phi(x)$.

But not every point $(x_0,y_0)\in S$ is the center of such a window $W$. The equation $f(x,y)=0$ could define a lemniscate (figure 8), and in the neighborhood of the self-intersection no representation of $S$ in the form $y=\phi(x)$ is possible.